# How to prevent Wordpress from abbreviating long slugs?

Tags: links, slug

By default, WordPress cut some words from long titles of posts, How to prevent Wordpress from abbreviating long slugs?

Comment: Could you please provide an example? On top of my head I am not sure why would it limit, other than possibly length limit on database field.

Answer (score 1):

Without you sharing a post title and its resulting slug to see what is happening, I can only guess. But a lot of the time [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words), or extremely common words, are stripped from slugs. This would be words like `the`, `a`, `an`, etc. The plugin Yoast SEO will do this if you're running it as well.

You can override WordPress' behavior though with the `save_post` hook though.

```
function my_custom_slug( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! wp_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

    // Temporarily Unhook to Prevent Infinite Loop
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_slug' );

    // Set the new Post Slug
    $my_slug =  sanitize_title( get_the_post_title( $post_id ) );

    // Update the Slug
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $my_slug,
    ) );

    // Rehook
    add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_slug' );

    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_slug' );
```

So what this code will do is, when the post is saved, take the post_title (e.g. `This is the title of my post`), sanitize it by removing HTML/PHP code as well as special characters, making it all lower-case letters, and converting all white space to `-`, storing it as `$my_slug`. So using my example, the title would become `this-is-the-title-of-my-post`. Then it will update the `post_name`, which contains the slug with the value of `$my_slug`.

NOTE: If you're doing this with a custom post type, the procedure is a little bit different and will need some changes and additional code in order to work.